# How firebase tells angularjs if user is logged in / out

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-security

Here is the snippet code, currently what I'm success is, when the user click login button.
it will redirect to `'page1'` and  if user click browser back button to `'/'` page will do the same.

Now the problem. If the user logged out at `page1`, suppose it will redirect to '/' but it won't even if the user click browser back button. So how firebase tells angularjs clear the response and back to `'/'` page?

```
var callback = function(error, user){
        if (user) {
            $rootScope.$apply(deferred.resolve(user));
        } else if (error) {
            $rootScope.$apply(deferred.reject(error));
        } else {
            //$rootScope.$apply(deferred.reject('user not login'));
        }
        return deferred.promise;
    }

var authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(firebaseRef, callback);

callback().then(function(response) {
  if (response) {
    $location.path('page1');
});
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding your question, vzhen. Are you trying to direct the user to `'/'` when they log out? Can you try to reword the problem? (Also, I think you are missing a curly in your last code block.)

Comment: @bennlich sry, i will update my question later.

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you need?

```js
var callback = function(error, user) {
    if (user) {
        // user logged in
        $rootScope.$apply($location.path('page1'));
    }
    else if (error) {
        console.log("There was an error logging in.");
    }
    else {
        // user logged out
        $rootScope.$apply($location.path('/'));
    }
}

var authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(firebaseRef, callback);
```